# Load Animated gif file using QMovie in Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu & Qt. I need to show busy status for other long operations. So, I was just trying to use waiting animation gif files to load instead using Progress bars.

I am using Eclipse Editor for Qt project.
Trolltech/../imageformat folder contains `libqgif.so` and `libqgif.so.debug`. I have copied these files in my debug folder too.

`loader.gif` is added in qrc file and kept in `/Resources` folder

IN MainWindow class I have added label and after setupUi(this) been called I call my `ShowMovie()` function as below:

```
ShowMovie() {

     QMovie *movie = NULL;
     movie  = new QMovie(":/Resources/loader.gif");
     if(movie->isValid()) {
         ui.label_3->setMovie(movie);
         movie->start();
     }
     else
         qDebug()<<"Movie is Invalid";
     qDebug()<<QImageReader::supportedImageFormats ();
}
```

Always isValid() function returns false & I got message that Movie is Invalid.
Last qDebug() returns

```
 ("bmp", "gif", "ico", "jpeg", "jpg", "mng", "pbm", "pgm", "png", "ppm",
  "svg", "svgz", "tif", "tiff", "xbm", "xpm")
```

i.e means gif support is available.

I have tried to call ShowMovie() function before loading Main UI and/or on button clicked. Both fails.

Provide help on what is to be corrected.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to copy librairies files `*.so`. 
Try creating the movie object with the full path to `loader.gif`. Does it work?
Then you have not setup correctly your resource system.

Either you have a syntax mistake in the qrc file which need to be fixed or you forgot to add it as a resource in the project file (`.pro`) using

```
RESOURCES     = myqresource.qrc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have checked qrc file is okay. And it is added into .pri file which is included in .pro file.

Comment: I found the issue.

The problem was same as you said that file was not found. When I have tried with absolute path it worked. It was strange that all my other image files are also in the same folder then why the gif file got failed.

I am thankful for your help.